# Techniques to evaluate the "twistiness" of a road in Google Maps?

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, maps

As per the title. I want to, given a Google maps URL, generate a twistiness rating based on how windy the roads are. Are there any techniques available I can look into?

What do I mean by twistiness? Well I'm not sure exactly. I suppose it's characterized by a high turn -to-distance ratio, as well as high angle-change-per-turn number. I'd also say that elevation change of a road comes in to it as well.

Comment: try to define what "twistiness" really is... different metrics force different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

I think that once you know exactly *what* you want to measure, the implementation is quite straightforward.

I can think of several measurements:

- the ratio of the road length to the distance between start and end (this would make a long single curve "twisty", so it is most likely not the complete answer)
- the number of inflection points per unit length (this would make an almost straight road with a lot of little swaying "twisty", so it is most likely not the complete answer)

These two could be combined by multiplication, so that you would have:

```
road-length        * inflection-points
--------------------------------------
start-end-distance * road-length
```

You can see that this can be shortened to "inflection-points per start-end-distance", which does seem like a good indicator for "twistiness" to me.

As for taking elevation into account, I think that making the whole calculation in three dimensions is enough for a first attempt.

You might want to handle left-right inflections separately from up-down inflections, though, in order to make it possible to scale the elevation inflections by some factor.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://www.hardingconsultants.co.nz/transportationconference2007/images/Presentations/Technical%20Conference/L1%20Megan%20Fowler%20Canterbury%20University.pdf as a starting point.

I'd assume that you'd have to somehow capture the road centreline from Google Maps as a vectorised dataset & analyse using GIS software to do what you describe. Maybe do a screen grab then a raster-to-vector conversion to start with.

Cumulative turn angle per Km is a commonly-used measure in road assessment. Vertex density is also useful. Note that these measures depend upon an assumption that vertices have been placed at some form of equal density along the line length whilst they were captured, rather than being manually placed. Running a GIS tool such as a "bendsimplify" algorithm on the line should solve this. I have written scripts in Python for ArcGIS 10 to define these measures if anyone wants them.

Sinuosity is sometimes used for measuring bends in rivers - see the help pages for Hawths Tools for ArcGIS for a good description. It could be misleading for roads that have major
changes in course along their length though.